# keychain: Warning: can't find gpg key; skipping

Tags: debian, keychain, gnupg, gpg-agent

I'm trying to use `keychain(1)` with my GnuPG key on Debian Testing. However, I get the following message with this command:

```
$ keychain --agents gpg MYPGPKEY

 * keychain 2.8.2 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Starting gpg-agent...
 * Warning: can't find MYPGPKEY; skipping
```

where `MYPGPKEY` is my actual key.

I can check that such key exits with the following command:

```
$ gpg --list-keys MYPGPKEY >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "key exists"
key exists
```

How can I add my gpg key with keychain?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an output parsing incompatibility between `keychain 2.8.2` and `gpg 2.2.4`, the two versions used in `Ubuntu 18.04`

I added the following to my `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, which fixed the issue:

```
keyid-format LONG
```

Source: https://github.com/funtoo/keychain/issues/107

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may be associated with your `gpg` and `keychain` version possible incompatibility. I can see that you are using 2.8.2 version which displays this error message that `2.7.0` doesn't.
Stable version of Debian is using `gnupg` 1.4.18-7+deb8u3`enter code here` and Testing is using `2.1.18-6`, which differ a lot.
Are you using your private key ID or your subkey ID?
My suggestion is changing the key ID provided to `keychain`

[Reference](http://blog.siphos.be/2016/10/gnupg-private-key-suddenly-missing/)

Comment: Debian stable now uses gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.18. The error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `keyid-format LONG` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` didn't work for me, but (per https://github.com/funtoo/keychain/issues/107#issuecomment-806252699) specifying `--agents "gpg,ssh"` in `keychain`'s arguments (in my case, `keychain --eval --agents "gpg,ssh" id_rsa id_ed25519 DEADBEEF`) did the trick.